# ZF2 Zend\Validator\DateStep Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds

Tags: php, validation, datetime, zend-framework2

so here is my situation I m setting up a form in which I include a datetime field

```
$this->form->add(array(
    'type'       => 'Zend\Form\Element\DateTime',
    'name'       => 'date',
    'options'    => array(
        'label'  => 'published_from',
        'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'class'     => 'datePicker form-control',
        'readonly'  => 'readonly',
        'data-type' => 'date'         
    ),
));
```

no min/max values or step, default values are applied, then I show it in the form like this

```
<?php echo $this->formDateTime($form->get('date')); ?>
```

now as soon as I submit this form the build in validation filter kicks in and after passing all initial validation it hits class Zend\Validator\DateStep lines 347-362

```
   if ($baseDate < $valueDate) {
        while ($baseDate < $valueDate) {
            $baseDate->add($step);

            if ($baseDate == $valueDate) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        while ($baseDate > $valueDate) {
            $baseDate->sub($step);
            if ($baseDate == $valueDate) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

where it falls in an apparently infinite loop and times out. the values for $baseDate and $valueDate when it hits that first if are $baseDate =

```
object(DateTime)#345 (3) { 
   ["date"]=> string(19) "1970-01-01 01:00:00" 
   ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) 
   ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/London" 
}
```

and $valueDate =

```
object(DateTime)#442 (3) { 
    ["date"]=> string(19) "2014-05-07 16:57:54" 
    ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) 
    ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/London" 
}
```

what am I doing wrong???

Comment: What is $step set as?

Comment: default is 1sec I just realised this, so it makes sense to error out if it has to do billions of iterations, I guess the question is why this part of the validation runs if there are no min-max values (meaning that one does not care about a date range if he doesnt put these values in), what if one just wants to make sure it's a valid date? I guess I will use a regular text field and add a date validator to the form...

Answer (score 0):

Although you have no min/max values or step, the error suggests that you have a DateStep InputFilter set up somewhere:

```
    $inputFilter->add( array(
        'name'     => 'deadline',
        'required' => false,
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name'    => 'DateStep',
                'options' => array(
                    'step' => new \DateInterval("P2D"),
                    'baseValue' => new \DateTime(),
                    'format'    => 'd/m/Y H:i:s',
                    'messages' => array( \Zend\Validator\DateStep::NOT_STEP => 'Must be at least two days in the future'),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

You will get this execution time error if you have the date validator set to use DateTime:

```
'type'       => 'Zend\Form\Element\DateTime',
```

Set it to:

```
'type'       => 'Zend\Form\Element\Date',
```

instead.